# How do i add my action bar to my view class?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-6.0-marshmallow

How do i add my action bar to view(Canvas) class?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);


    //set paint color

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //setContentView(new DrawView(this));


    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    //DrawView.setPaint(255, 235, 191, 47);
}
```

[image: Here is my project.]

Here is my project
and the tool bar is stored in activity_main.xml.

Visual representation of what i want :P
left screen shot is when i use `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`, right one is `//setContentView(new DrawView(this));`

[image]

Thanks guys! and if its ok can you guys incl. an explanation as well? I'm new to android programming :)

activity_main XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.nikol.touchpaint.MainActivity">
<!--    <view
        android:id="@+id/viewid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />-->

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/testText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="151dp"
        android:text="Hello World!" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button2"
        android:text="New Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="29dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
        android:text="New Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Why can't you put the Canvas view in an Activity with the Toolbar?

Comment: @cricket_007 Do you mean like this? http://puu.sh/qu73r/5df21ed733.png

Comment: Not exactly... How would you get the Toolbar there? You can add your DrawView into the `activity_main.xml`, you shouldn't need to set it from the Java code

Comment: @cricket_007 oh i did but the problem is when i do this `//setContentView(new DrawView(this));` the thing disappear.

Comment: I don't know what you mean... You need a content view if you want to see anything. So your best option is to use `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

Comment: @cricket_007 but when i do that my drawview class will not show Q_Q.

Comment: Can you please [edit] the question and show the XML layout?

Comment: @cricket_007 so if you look at the second screen shot. the right side is when i use `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` the left one is `setContentView(new DrawView(this));`. and what i want is, i want the tool bar to appear in the drawview. :)

Comment: Why do you not have a `<com.example.nikol.touchpaint.DrawView` element in the XML, then? That is what I said in my first comment.

Comment: @cricket_007 oh sorry Q_Q, can you show me how to do that please Q_Q.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the layout editor for the view with the toolbar, and the buttons, scroll down in the editor to where you see "Custom View".

From there, you can start typing, and you can add your custom `View` class and add wherever in that XML you want.

[image: custom view]

Answer (score 0):

Your activity_main.xml should look like this :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/contentView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.example.nikol.touchpaint.DrawView
        android:id="@+id/drawView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

</RelativeLayout>
```

then in your activity do

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    DrawView drawView = findViewById(R.id.drawView);
}
```